# Why is pivothigh/pivotlow showing NaN for bars?

Tags: pine-script

The pivothigh / pivotlow functions return the high/low within the leftbars/rightbars arguments. How is it possible certain bars to return NaN when from each bar's perspective there is high/low within the laftbars/rightbars boundaries ? In fact most bars show NaN, how does it choose from which  bar's perspective it will calculate ?

I expected  each bar to show a pivot point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pivothigh / pivotlow will only return a value on the bar that creates a pivot point.

Example if you use `ta.pivothigh(5,5)` it returns true on the 5th bar to the right of `bar_index[5]` with a lower high, if there are 5 bars to the left of `bar_index[5]` with a lower high as well.